# Cannot comment on particular post

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

On the Android app, the button to add a comment did not show up on this question:

[Topic Challenge: Original stand-alone movies [completed]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1812)

I was able to add a comment by opening the question in my mobile browser.

Comment: No repro. Make sure to first visit the [main site](http://movies.stackexchange.com/) with the app, make sure you're logged in. From what I remember, you can't login from the app in a child meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That was probably the issue; I'm now seeing the button.